# Get controls from nested form group

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormGroup, nested in another FormGroup, where I want to get a certain control with get().

I tried the following solution, which doesn't work:

```
formGroup.get('formGroupKey').get('formControlKey');
```

But this throws an error. The first get() works (and correctly returns a FormGroup), but the second get throws an exception (path.split is not a function)

Any idea how I can solve that?

@Update

I solved it now this way (which is not a pretty solution though):

```
formGroup.get(tab.id)['controls'][segment.id];
```

Comment: formGroupName.get('formGroupKey.formGroupKey')

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately that solution doesn't work for me because the keys are variables (objects) itself. The first key is 'tab.id' and the second one: 'segment.id'. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: can you add your class code?

Comment: Please see my update in my post. Managed to solve it somehow, but the solution is kind of ugly

Comment: I does not clarify anything you should at least put the code of what you are trying to  achieve an how. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This should work: `this.formGroup.get(varibaleKey).get(variableKey2)`

Here is some code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  form: FormGroup;

  key1: string = 'test1';
  key2: string = 'test2';

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      test1: this.formBuilder.group({
        test2: ['testValue']
      }),
      another: ['testValue']
    });
    console.log(this.form.get(this.key1).get(this.key2));
  }
}
```

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipman8